# Norm of a dot product?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading a [paper](http://driving.stanford.edu/papers/ISER2010.pdf) and is rather perplexed by the following equation. Particularly, inside the double bar || which I believe is the norm, there is a dot product. If that is the case, what does it mean to get the norm of a scalar value?

[image]

Comment: It's probably just supposed to be an absolute value. That is, it's a typo.

Comment: If that's the case , then minimising that absolute is the same as minimising the square right ?

Comment: I would send an email to ask the authors.